# iOS - In App Purchase- How to add policy section when paying?

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have In App Purchase setup on my iOS application. The only issue I'm facing is that I can't figure out how to add a policy section when purchasing a subscription. Could it be related to Sandbox/TestFlight vs production? Or is it a setting in StoreKit? Any help is appreciated.

**This is what I have:**

[In app purchase without policy]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RouJu.png

**This is what I would like to do:**

[In app purchase with policy]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MouTz.jpg

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can add this from codeside. Apple handles it and shows the test to the user Accordingly.
[image: See the Picture]

download the sample code from wwdc2021
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10114/

Comment: Cool thanks! I tried it and it did work for some options. Except I don't know where that data is being set. It might be a config in IAP.

Comment: which data?@SomeCoder